# Is there a simple way to use WHERE on time stamp for month

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a table, which has several thousand rows in it, each of which has a time stamp in this format:

> ** YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS** *so 2014-01-10 04:20:26*

Is it possible to use a simple method to get MySQL Select, presumably using WHERE, to get all articles, saved in January say. Alternatively I guess the only other option is to loop through each row, split the string and add it to another string if it is. Not ideal to say the least.

Note: While I can change this table the data is being fed from a third party so it isn't possible to save the month/year in its own cell.

Comment: You shouldn't save them in different cells, this is EXACTLY the way they are supposed to be saved!

Comment: Just January or January of an Year like Jan 2014 ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the DATE functions?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Ideally Year and Month

Comment: Leave them in the same cells!! Your table will index (hopefully) the single cell and it will be much more optimized and your queries will be ALOT easier to sort by date/times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the string to a DATE, then use the [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function to extract the month and check against that.

For example:

```
 select * from tbl where month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) = 1
```

And for month and year:

```
 select * from tbl 
 where month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) = 1
 and year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) = 2014
```

Comment: Why use `STR_TO_DATE()` when the value is already a [valid literal format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html)?

Comment: @eggyal: I wasn't aware you could use the MONTH function on a string, but if that works, go for it.

Comment: Yes @cdmckay just do MONTH(table.dateField) = 1

Comment: One advantage to using STR_TO_DATE might be that it would ensure the date has the correct format, and not accidentally accept another valid literal date string.

Comment: @eggyal: For example, imagine you accidentally had `30150721` in the column. If we used STR_TO_DATE, we would get an error. If we used the literal directly, it would silently accept it as the 3015-07-21.

Comment: Ah, I concede that that's a fair point.  However, do take note of [the OP's clarifying comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056507/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-where-on-time-stamp-for-month#comment31661695_21056507): he wants to match on both month *and* year.

Comment: @eggyal: Thanks, I've added an additional example for month and year.

Comment: @eggyal and cdmckay Good answers either way. I thought the non numeric characters would screw around with it, evident not :)

Comment: @tim.baker: Not at all - this is MySQL's native timestamp format.  Be aware, however, that if your column is indexed then cdmckay's approach will result in a full table scan (and requires MySQL to obtain the result of the function calls for each record), whereas my approach can take full advantage of the index.

Comment: @eggyal: When MySQL uses a date literal, is it not doing the conversion behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >= '2014-01-01' AND date < '2014-02-01'
```

Comment: . . I agree.  Converting the string to a date is totally unnecessary.